# Improvements in the given Regex in Objective C

Tags: regex

I have implemented below given regex to check that the given 6-digit number is not repeated and not in sequence/reverse-sequence in objective c.

Regex: `(?!(\\d)\\1+$|(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5}\\d$|(?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5}\\d$)\\d{6}$`

I am not sure that whether it is optimal solution or not.
Does anyone know the optimal solution for the above mentioned problem?
Please help me for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: example of sequence ?

Comment: I believe you wanted to match a string consisting of 6 digits. Add a `^` at the very beginning before `(?!`

Comment: @FlyingGambit, I mean sequence  is something like 123456, 987654

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,Yes you are right, I wanted to match the string which has 6 digits. Does it make any difference of using ^ instead of (?!

Comment: I did not say *instead*. *Add* it, it is a must if you use it in a method that does not require a full string match, and your regex will works fast and safe. [Test it here](https://regex101.com/r/s9zC0f/2).

Comment: Why did you ask for improvements? What trouble have you got with the pattern? How is it used?